# Finding relationship between complex determinant and real determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

I am working on the following question:

> Let $V$ be an $n$ dimensional complex vector space and let $\phi : V \to V$ be a complex linear map. Let $W$ be $V$ considered as a real vector space (of dimension $2n$) and let $\psi$ be the same map $\phi$ considered as a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map $W \to W$. What is the relationship between the complex number $\det \phi$ and the real number $\det \psi$? (Of course, you should prove your claim.)

Does anyone have any advice/hints on how to work with this problem?

Comment: One approach might be to use Jordan Canonical form/existence of an upper triangular form for matrices of complex numbers to choose a nice basis for $V$ as a complex vector space. Given a basis for $V$ so that $\phi$ is upper triangular, can you produce a basis for $W$ so that $\psi$ is block upper triangular? What are the blocks on the diagonal?

Comment: As with all problems, it can be worth trying to start with a concrete example. In particular, try $n = 1$, $V = \mathbb{C}$, and identify $\psi$ with a representation as a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Hint: https://web.archive.org/web/20140505161153/http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jrs/gazette/blocks.pdf